# Asan don't report leak info

Tags: centos, g++, address-sanitizer

I write a simple c++ program that use new function and don't use delete function, then I use asan, but it not report.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p = new int[50];
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        *(p + i ) = i;
    }
    cout << *p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

then `./g++ main.cpp -lasan -L/root/local/lib64/ -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g`

and print 0, but not report delete leak . why ?

if I use `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib64/libasan.so.0.0.0`, then `./g++ main.cpp`
report

```
g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program collect2)
0x40c400 execute
    ../../gcc/gcc.c:2823
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
```

it look like collect2 core dump ,so I run `cd libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.5/ && ./colloct2`, report `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I use source to install gcc-4.8.5, centos 6.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `LD_PRELOAD` when you *run* your program, not build it?

Comment: It build ok, if export LD_PRELOAD=.     But don't report memory leak .

Answer (score 1):

gcc-4_8-branch doesn't even contain libsanitizer/lsan/ directory. Please try more recent GCC versions. by https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/699